# How can we capture the coverage failure output from Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, circleci

I am trying to get ahold of these strings to fail a CI, has anyone successfully done this, and if so, how?

`Jest: Coverage for branches (40.15%) does not meet global threshold (50%)
Jest: Coverage for lines (66%) does not meet global threshold (75%)`

There is a PR that seems to address a similar issue, but when I run with the code from this PR, I can't capture this output.

https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/3554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coverage output is going to `stderr`.

Try this `jest --coverage 2> coverage-output.txt`